# Filtering get_permalink in Jetpack / ShareDaddy

Tags: plugins, permalinks, filters, plugin-jetpack

I recently changed my permalink structure from `/YYYY/MM/%post_name%/` to `/%post_name%/`, and lost my tweet counts and likes (provided by [Jetpack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/)) in the process.

To fix this, I want Jetpack to use the old-style permalinks for stories dated prior to the change. Unfortunately, it looks like I'll have to [filter the content of `get_permalink` to do it](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-jetpack-by-wordpresscom-support-for-sharing_permalink-filter-inconsistent#post-3083508).

So I have my function to return the fixed permalinks:

```
function jetpack_sharing_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {

    $url_change_date = strtotime( "23 February 2013" ); // Date of the URL changeover
    $post_date = get_the_time( 'U', $post->ID );

    if ( $post_date < $url_change_date ) :
        $url_date_prefix = "/" . date( "Y", $post_date ) . "/" . date( "m", $post_date );
        $permalink = str_replace( get_site_url(), get_site_url() . $url_date_prefix, $permalink );
    endif;

    return $permalink;

}
```

1. How do I use it to filter the output of `get_permalink`? Is my theme's `functions.php` too late?
2. How would I get started writing a 'baby' plugin (as suggested) so that `get_permalink` is only filtered for Jetpack's Sharing feature?

Thanks in advance.